# Creating First Row as a header with awk

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Previously I was using kali linux to code my bash file so it has no issue with the command, but after since I use ubuntu I realized it does not work on ubuntu and can't find any solution to this problem yet.

**Ori Code**

`tr ':' '\t' < venue.txt | tr ' ' '_____" | awk -F "\t\ '$1=Name {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' Name=$Name | column -t --table-columns "Number:", "Type:", "Capacity:" , "Status:" | tr '_____' ' '`

**venue.txt**

```
B:B01:Random:6:This is a long message
C:C01:Lab:5:This is message
```

I wanted the output be something like this, without the use of column --table-columns since somehow ubuntu does not support it, best would be awk

```
(When name==b, output be like)
Number     Type      Capacity      Status
 B01       Random        6         This is a long message
```

Comment: The command you posted appears to be garbled -- the quotes don't match up properly. Also, `tr '_____' ' '` doesn't make sense, since `tr` does single-character substitutions, not string substitutions. Also, what is the command doing, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: ubuntu `column` (from bsdextrautils) does support `--table-columns`

Comment: your awk  command makes no sense, `$6` will never have content since `venue.txt` only has 4 colons (5 fields). And `$1=Name` assigns to `$1` it does not compare

Comment: Because somehow it would read `This is a long message` into 5 column so I used ` tr ' ' '_____' ` in order to brute force making it into 1 column and transform it back

Comment: somehow when i use `--table-columns`  it would say invalid option

Comment: what is output of `dpkg -S "$(which column)"`  ?

Comment: you state *`output be something like this`* and then show inconsistent spacing in the sample output; if the format of the output is important to you then consider updating the sample output to show a more consistent spacing (same number of spaces between widest field of each column, left- or center-justified in each field, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
tr ':' '\t' < venue.txt |
tr ' ' '_____" |
awk -F "\t\ '$1=Name {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' Name=$Name |
column -t --table-columns "Number:", "Type:", "Capacity:" , "Status:" |
tr '_____' ' '
```

- `tr` is not needed; `awk` has `-F`
- the second `tr` command has a double-quote (`"`) where there should be a single-quote, so the entire command meaning changes (the `awk` command becomes extra arguments to `tr` - which would give a syntax error). Was this a typo for `tr ' ' '_____'` ?
- `tr 'x' 'yyyyy'` == `tr 'x' 'y'`
- Was `awk -F "\t\ '...` a typo for `awk -F '\t' '...` ?
- `$1=Name` assigns the value of variable `Name` to the first field. Perhaps you intended to compare (`==`) ?
- `$6` will always be empty since `venue.txt` has only 5 fields
- `tr 'xxxxx' 'y'` == `tr 'xxxxx' 'yyyyy'` == `tr 'x' 'y'`

---

If you are trying to print the record in `venue.txt` whose first column equals the value of bash variable `Name`, without printing the name itself, and converting the `:` delimiter to a tab and adding a header line to the output, you can do everything with a single `awk` command:

```
awk -F: -v OFS='\t' '
    BEGIN { print "Number","Type","Capacity","Status" }
    $1==Name { print $2,$3,$4,$5 }
' Name="$Name" venue.txt
```

It would not be hard to use `awk` to align the columns but it needs two passes and is more effort than using `column`:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '
    BEGIN { print "Number","Type","Capacity","Status" }
    $1==Name { print $2,$3,$4,$5 }
' Name="$Name" venue.txt | column -t -s:
```

Answer (score -2):

Somehow managed doing it after using this

```
tr ':' '\t' < venue.txt | tr ' ' '_____" | awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN {printf("%-4s %-1s %-3s %s %s\n" "Number:", "Type:", "Capacity:" , "Status:")}; %$1=Name {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' Name=$Name | column -t | tr '_____' ' '
```

Comment: No, you didn't. That awk command has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).